# Taking data from a function to use it in another one in C language

Tags: arrays, c, function, struct

```c
typedef struct Projet
{
    /* data */
    char theme[20];
    int diff;
    char etudiant1[4]; //L'Etudiant 1 affecté dans le projet par Matricule
    char etudiant2[4]; //L'Etudiant 2 affecté dans le projet par Matricule
}Projet;

/****---Function to add a project---****/
int AddProjet(int nmbProjet){
    
    int rows;

    Projet TabProj[nmbProjet]; // Table to store the projects

    /* --Loop to get the project info-- */
    for ( rows = 0; rows < nmbProjet; rows++)
    {
        printf("\t--> Theme %d : ",rows+1);
        scanf(" %s",&TabProj[rows].theme);
        /****Project Theme****/

        printf("\t--> La difficulte [1-10] : ");
        scanf(" %i",&TabProj[rows].diff);
        /*****its difficulty*****/

        printf("\n");
    }
}
/*****************************************/
```

```
/****---Function to add 2 students in a project---****/
int AffEtudiant(int nmbPrjAff){

    int choix_prj_aff;

    Projet TabProj[nmbPrjAff];//Table of the projects

    puts("--> Choisir un projet :");//Choose a project
    
/***--Loop to list all the project that the user has added--***/
    for (int i = 0; i < nmbPrjAff; i++)
    {
        printf("\t%d- Projet %d :\n",i+1,i+1);
        printf("\t -> %s",TabProj[i].theme);
        printf("\n");
        printf("\t -> %d",TabProj[i].diff);
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    printf("--> Votre choix est : ");//Choice
    scanf("%d",&choix_prj_aff);

    printf("\n<----------------------->\n\n");

    
     printf("--> Entrer le Matricule de 1 etudiant : ");//Enter the code of student 1 
     scanf("%s",&TabProj[choix_prj_aff-1].etudiant1);
     
     printf("--> Entrer le Matricule de 2 etudiant : ");//Enter the code of student 2 
     scanf("%s",&TabProj[choix_prj_aff-1].etudiant2);
        
    printf("\n<----------------------->\n\n");   
}
/*****************************************************/
```

The problem is when I try to add two students after adding the projects the second function which is called (`AffEtudiant`) can't get the projects data (theme/difficulty) to list them. Instead it shows some garbage values, even though I called the same table that I have set in the function of adding projects (`Project TabProj[]`);

How can I get that table of data to use it in another function?

Comment: Create the `TabProj` variable in the function that *calls* `AddProjet` and `AffEtudiant`, then pass `TabProj` as an argument to those functions instead.

Comment: Both of the function you've shown say they will return an `int` but neither of them actually do. That's undefined behavior.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&TabProj ...` risks buffer overflow.   Use a width.  `scanf("%19s",&TabProj...`

Comment: Detail: `scanf("%3s",&TabProj[choix_prj_aff-1].etudiant1);`

Comment: Yoshikage, post sample input.

Comment: @RetiredNinja "neither of them actually do. That's undefined behavior. " --> I think it is only UB if the calling code attempts to use the return values.  There is some SO Q&A on that. Hmmmm.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I prefer to see it as always a bug. If the possibility is there eventually someone is going to try and use the return value and hopefully have a problem right away rather than having everything seem fine until it goes to production. :)

Answer (score 1):

`TabProj` is a local variable inside each of the functions and it gets freed once the function exists. You should define it **outside** the functions and pass a point to it to the function when you want the function to update it.

Comment: `TabProj` is an array of structure, its value changes depending on how many projects the user want. i have tried to set it outside of the functions like this `struct Projet TabProjet[nmbProjet]` but it appears as an error **expression must have a constant value** . How can i do it then ?

Comment: @Yoshikage allocate it dynamically with `malloc`?